# "std::transform" compiles without qualified name lookup on multiple compilers?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, namespaces, clang

I was writing a library in C++ when I discovered that calls to `std::transform` were unexpectedly compiling fine without fully qualifying the calls with the `std::` namespace prefix. According to the C++ documentation `std::transform` is defined in the `std::` namespace so it should not compile without fully qualifying the name.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3 };

    // "transform" is supposed to be in the namespace "std::"???
    transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [](const auto& value) {
        return value + 1;
        });
}
```

At first I thought this was a bug in the Microsoft implementation of the standard library since I was working in Visual Studio, but then I tested it out with a bunch of different compilers on https://godbolt.org/ and it seemed to compile without errors on other compilers too!

[gcc example](https://godbolt.org/z/55h5d3)

[clang example](https://godbolt.org/z/ex4bjK)

[MSVC example](https://godbolt.org/z/chqYq5)

Changing the `transform` call to `::transform` causes the compilation to fail so it is clear that there is no symbol for `transform` in the global namespace.

My guess is that somewhere in the `<algorithm>` header file someone accidentally typed `using std::transform;` in the global namespace which would make the function available to call without the `std::` prefix... but that would be considered bad practice and would be a bug in the standard library implementation wouldn't it?

Did I just find a bug in the standard library implementation for ***multiple*** compilers!? If so, how would I even go about reporting such a bug?

Comment: It's called "argument-dependent lookup". An unqualified function name is looked up in the namespaces associated with any function arguments. In this case `v.begin()` has some iterator type `std::` something . This is how overloaded operator calls work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a bug<sup>1</sup>. This is [argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (aka Koenig lookup).

When an argument to a function is in a particular namespace, the compiler will look in that namespace for the function itself.

In this case, the relationship may not be obvious, but the argument to the function is what `v.begin()` returns, which is something like `std::vector<int>::iterator`<sup>2</sup>, so the compiler looks in namespace `std` for the function as well.

---

<sup>1. It is, however, sufficiently unexpected behavior that some not only would, but have argued that it's a bug in the language definition.

2. But that might not really be its exact name. It's useful for vectors to have the same iterator types, even if they have different allocator types, and to do that the iterator type will often be defined outside the vector.</sup>

Comment: D'oh! I definitely knew that but it seemed so unexpected I didn't even think of ADL! Definitely one of the more obscure features of C++ haha

Comment: ADL is important for things like `std::cout << "Hello, world\n";`. Without it you'd need some other way to tell the compiler that the `<<` is defined in namespace `std`. With ADL it looks in `std` because `std::cout` is defined there. That's the original use-case for ADL, and nobody foresaw problems with making it apply universally. With hindsight, some argue that it should be limited to operators.